# docker - postgres upgrade 11 to 12 postmaster issue

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-upgrade

I used this https://github.com/tianon/docker-postgres-upgrade to upgrade postgres from 11 to 12 version & facing issue while upgrade, got error - "postmaster servicing the old cluster"

Here using docker container for 11 & 12 in separately, also scale down docker service before that upgarde, but not sure why this postmaster issue came & how to fix this.??

```
docker run --rm \
    -v aip-pgs-data:/var/lib/postgresql/$OLD/data \
    -v aip-pg12-data:/var/lib/postgresql/$NEW/data \
    "tianon/postgres-upgrade:$OLD-to-$NEW"
```

Above docker run cmd part of logs:--

```
Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/data -l logfile start


There seems to be a postmaster servicing the old cluster.
Please shutdown that postmaster and try again.
Failure, exiting
0a5839ad7309d6256510fe89513774a16c4f26ec6a827f9f0089fd8cc10254cb
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Please shutdown that postmaster and try again." - did you try shutting down the old postmaster like it asks you to?

Comment: @RichardHuxton before running the above "tianon/postgres-upgrade" docker run, i have scaled postgres docker service to 0 like ( docker service scale pgs=0 ), But still throwing why..? Did i wrong..? Or any other way to stop postmaster..?

Comment: It seems like rather than doing `docker service scale pgs=0`, you need to actually `docker stop` the v11 container

Comment: @RichardHuxton I have tried that but still getting some error like below after manual stop docker container. 
error-:

Comment: @RichardHuxton I have tried that but still getting some error like below after manual stop docker container.  Error:-

Comment: Error :--- 
Success. You can now start the database server using:
    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/data -l logfile start
initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
The source cluster was not shut down cleanly.
Failure, exiting

Comment: I tried a longer stop_grace_period so that postgresql server will have enough time to stop everything when it receives the SIGTERM (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/server-shutdown.html). Then postgres stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a longer stop_grace_period so that postgresql server will have enough time to stop everything when it receives the SIGTERM (postgresql.org/docs/11/server-shutdown.html). Then postgres stopped

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the postgres server isn't shutting down cleanly before docker kills it, but stopping the process will also restart the container.

Another option is to disable restarts

```
docker update --restart=no $CONTAINER_ID
```

then exec into the container

```
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID bash
```

find the `pg_ctl` binary, `su` to the `postgres` user, then run `pg_ctl stop`

```
# which pg_ctl
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl
# su postgres
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl stop
```